# On click one button browser tab should close ( its not a popup window )

Tags: javascript, jquery, mozilla

I have one html

```
<a href="#" onclick="close_window()">
    close me
</a>
```

i want to close the browser tab when i click on close button but my problems are :
1 ) i cant open my page in popup window.
2 ) i have no other option :-(

i tried to search the solution but didnt get any exact answer.
**`PROBLEM HAPPENING IN FIREFBOX ONLY .window.close working fine in ie and chrome.`**

```
<script>
function close_window() {
 setTimeout(function(){
alert(window.location)
ww = window.open(self.location, '_self');
ww.close();
},1000)
}
</script>
```

This is the script i am using for closing the browser

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems just an hack in order to do something of prohibited. So I won't recommend this

Comment: Unconvinced that there's no other option. Why not navigate to a page that says "it's now safe to close this window" or similar.

Comment: so there is no other option via js ??

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in FireFox:

```
function closeWindow() {
    netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserWrite");
    alert("This will close the window");
    window.open('','_self');
    window.close();
}

closeWindow();
```